# the probability of event A + the probability of A's complementary doesn't add up to 1

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $12$ different balls and $10$ numbered cells, the balls are randomly distributed. I need to calculate the probability that cell number $1$ got **at least** $3$ balls. I have $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to choose 3 balls and the probability that they are in cell no.$1$ is $\frac{1}{10^3}$, so $$P(3+) = \frac{\binom{12}{3}\cdot 10^9}{10^{12}}$$ I wanted to check my answer by calculating the probability of the complementary event and verify that the sum is 1 but I got $$P(0)=\frac{9^{12}}{10^{12}}, P(1)=\frac{12\cdot 9^{11}}{10^{12}}, P(2)=\frac{66\cdot 9^{10}}{10^{12}} \Longrightarrow P(0)+P(1)+P(2)+P(3+) \approx 1.1$$ am I missing some intersection? or did I do something wrong in $P(3+)$ (or any of the other events) calculations?

Comment: Your calculation of $P(3+)$ is incorrect. If you multiply that number by $\left( 1 - \frac{9}{10} \right)^9$ it would be the probability that cell number $1$ has exactly $3$ balls. To get the probability of at least $3$ balls you'd have to sum over similar expressions for $4$ balls, etc. (So the complement is easier to study.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done for trying to check your answer. I would calculate things like this ( use as you say the law of total probability : $P(3+)+P(0)+P(1)+P(2)=1$ so $P(3+)=1-(P(0)+P(1)+P(2))$. Where these probabilities are easier to work out.

$$P(0)=(\frac{9}{10})^{12} ,~~~ P(1)=12(\frac{1}{10})(\frac{9}{10})^{11} ,~~~P(2)={12\choose 2}(\frac{1}{10})^2(\frac{9}{10})^{10}  $$

For instance $P(2)$ there are ${12\choose 2}$ ways of picking 2 balls for the first cell, each way has the probability $(\frac{1}{10})^2(\frac{9}{10})^{10} $ of happening.

Answer (score 0):

Chance of cell 1 getting exactly 3 balls is

$$ \binom{12}{3} \times \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^3 \times \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^9.$$

You can relate this computation to the binomial expansion of $$\left(\frac{1}{10} + \frac{9}{10}\right)^{(12)}.$$